# How to create a Pinterest-style layout using ionic?

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and stuck at how to create a Pinterest-style layout using ionic. It's like two-wide list of variable height items. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Something like [this](https://blog.pinterest.com/sites/blog/files/article/fields/field_image/2014112502.jpg)?

Because of Ionic’s use of [CSS flexbox](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/using-the-grid/), you can create one row with two equally spaced columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
</div>
```

After that you can use [ionic cards](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-images) with a ng-repeat inside of both columns.

Another good way to figure things out is to digg in to the existing themes provided by the [ionic market](https://market.ionic.io/themes). I hope this gets you started...

Comment: you're welcome @moyuan... pleas mark the answer if it's correct

Comment: If I have 1 list of objects, how can I distribute the list to 2 columns?

Comment: just use $index inside your ng-repeat. In the first column use {{list[$index]}} and in the second one use {{list[$index+1]}}. Or you could just split the list into 2 seperate lists inside your js file.

Answer (score 0):

in html file create this two level structure:

```
<div class="pins">
  <div class="pin" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <img [src]="item.mage"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

while `pins` and `pin` css styles is:

```
.pins {
  column-count: 10;
  .pin {
     margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
     display: inline-block;
  }
}
```